# magento data migration error in Customer Attribute step

Tags: magento2-migration-tool

getting the error while migrating data from magento CE 1.9.2.2 to magento EE 2.1

```
    Error:
    [2016-08-29 10:10:00][DEBUG][mode: data][stage: data migration]

[step: Customer Attributes Step][table: customer_entity]: migrating 100% [============================] 

Remaining Time: 1 sec [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter 

number: number of bound variables does n ot match number of tokens
```

Anybody please help.

Thanks Meena R

Comment: Exception trace:

Comment: if you had find solution can you please post it because i am facing same issue. Thanks in advance !

Comment: I had found the solution. please export your customer_entity table as CSV and check for wrong values I have found the invalid emails.

Comment: and also I have found null and some invalid emails - for eg: somename without @gmail.com and some special characters. This may help you to solve the issues.